# Deploy APIFunction on my server?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, api

I have an APIFunction and I would l like to serve it from my own machine. I already have a license and an AWS account and I don't want to pay cloud credits or run my code on someone else's hardware. Is there anyway to serve MMA results from my machine? Note: I don't have the money to afford an Enterprise Private Cloud.

Comment: Afaict only EPC and PC work with APIFunctions out of the box. You could try to build on top of WebMathematica or even regular Mathematica but 1) it requires work 2) to expose WL online you are required to have at least WebMathematica license.

Comment: Whatever is said here can be out of date or won't include special deals so have you asked WRI Support/Sales about alternatives?

Comment: You could use a process to link into a server, but it would be slow and synchronous!